# Design interrogation on proper use of the "side effect" notion of ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects

I'm writing this to know if I get it right or not.

On examples found online, the pattern usually goes like this (example here on add/delete actions on the state and on a remote database) :

effects.ts :

```
@Effect()
add$ = this.action$
  .ofType(ADD)
  .switchMap((action: Action) => {
     return this.http.put(...)
       .map( response => response.json() )
       .map( response => Observable.of({ type: ADD_SUCCESS, payload: action.payload }))
       .catch( response => Observable.of({ type: ADD_FAIL, payload: response.status }))
```

reducer.ts

```
...
switch (action.type){
  case 'ADD_SUCCESS':
     ...
     return new_state;
  case 'ADD_FAIL':
     return state;
}
```

It works, **but the speed of execution as felt by the user depends on how fast the network is**. So I came up with a pattern that bets on the high probability that no error will be returned from the API:

reducer.ts

```
...
switch (action.type){
  case 'ADD':
     ... // make the adequate addition
     return new_state;
  case 'ADD_FAIL':
     ... // delete the addition previously made
     return new_state;
}
```

effects.ts :

```
@Effect()
add$ = this.action$
  .ofType(ADD)
  .switchMap((action: Action) => {
     return this.http.put(...)
       .map( response => response.json() )
       .catch( response => Observable.of({ type: ADD_FAIL, payload: action.payload }))
```

In this pattern, the action of saving to database really is a "side effect". In the unlikely but possible case where the API return an error, then a second action is taken to undo the first action.

But I haven't found yet this design in the examples given online: Since I'm an amateur dev, I wonder if I missed something that makes it wrong/dangerous/inefficient in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say there is anything wrong/dangerous/inefficient about it.  Everything is subjective to your program requirements.  If you are dealing with *really* slow networks, then that needs to be taken into account.

But then in that situation, if a problem goes wrong, then user won't know about it until the Action completes anyway.  With the scenario of a *really* slow network and having both `SUCCESS` and `FAIL` Actions, then the user is more confident in the data they have because a `SUCCESS` action had to fire.  If you bypass the `SUCCESS` action, then the user could be working away and not know that their data is incorrect until the `FAIL` action occurs. The result may be minor, or it may interrupt the user workflow.

Now, in general, the time it takes to submit a `put` or `post` request and get a response should be rather short.  And your `SUCCESS` or `FAIL` actions should not be so large that they take a long time to compute.

Take for example a checkout system.  A user goes to checkout and `posts` to the server.  You don't want to route to a confirmation page until you know whether the post was successful or not.  So having separate `SUCCESS` and `FAIL` actions are necessary in that situation.

I think it provides the best user experience to be make sure the data they see is accurate and not rolling back changes after a failure.  If the user `posts` or `puts` something to the server, the `SUCCESS` action should then add it to the application state and not before then and also possible user notification.  A `FAIL` action would handle user notification, potential logging, etc depending upon the application.

Another example:  Say a user is editing an online profile.  If they click 'Save' then you want the user to be notified upon a successful save on the server.  That way they don't navigate away from the page thinking 'I hope it saved, I didn't get a response.'

I would say in most scenarios it is appropriate to have both a `SUCCESS` and `FAIL` actions.  But like I said, everything is subjective to your application and what is acceptable to your users, in your environment.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Tyler for your quick and precise reply. I do agree in the examples you give that the classic design is better. In the proposed design and for non-critical data at stake (such as in my project), I'll work on giving the proper UI to the user so that he/she understands that his/her action hasn't gone through.